# How to see what a website does during a process?

Tags: web, reverse-engineering

There is a website where I upload a file and then the site performs some heavy actions on the file and then downloads the file again. How can I view the code of what happens during the process?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on web page and select `view page source` to see code of the HTML website. You can also select `inspect` to see more details of the code, error, etc.

Comment: It is not that simple. I tried this but it doesnt show me the "script" behind this process

Comment: Did it show any error or any messages when you try the above method? Could you provide the website link if it's not private?

Answer (score 0):

Web applications are consist of two parts: **Back-end** and **Front-end**
It depends on process. if the process is happening in front-end you can use **Element inspection** to check html and javascript code.
But something like image processing usually happens in back-end (where the webserver runs PHP , ASP , ...). 
So you **cannot** view the source or do reverse engineering from a **legitimate** way.